# I am learning how to write an AJAX web app. What is the proper way to set up IIS?

Tags: web-applications

Should I be even using IIS? I copied a file from w3schools.com and I cannot get it to work on my local pc. Someone suggested I might not be referencing ajax_info.txt correctly. When I tried using a file reference this also did not work. Please help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I wrote my own ajax_info.txt and put "hello" in it. Please assist.

Comment: Have you put the ajax_info.txt file in the same place that this HTML file?

Comment: Yes both are in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\javascript Projects\ajax.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise than my previous comment, the file ajax_info.txt is not dynamically generated by a server process like PHP or ASP.NET; it's a constant file and therefore the above should work with any web server of any kind.

If this doesn't work then it's either because it is not at the right location or the suffix .txt is blocked for some reason on the server.  Try renaming it to ajax_info.html if you have verified its location.

Comment: And how are you calling the above file from your browser?  In other way, what is the exact URL address that you are putting in the web browser bar address?

Comment: Just to be clear, I hope that you didn't try with something like C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\javascript Projects\ajax\test.html in the browser bar address for testing your ajax file.